# handling basic authentication with php- predifined variable AUTH_TYPE

Tags: php, http-headers, basic-authentication

why in my following script I don't have the index of AUTH_TYPE in the $_SERVER supper global array?

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="hi please enter your password and username"');
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'); // this will show the log in box
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button'; // this will show if the user click cancel 
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
    echo "<p> {$_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE']} your authentication type.</p>";
    var_dump($_SERVER) ;

}
?>
```

Comment: I am using an apache server from the xampp package

Comment: what is the value that is supposed to be in the AUTH_TYPE index? is it supposed to be the string "basic"?